# How to enable firebase phone verification in flutter web ? I have tried many ways but it doesn't seems to work, SMS code need to be sent to the user

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web, sms-verification

I want to implement the phone verification by sending OTP using firebase, how to do this? . I have tried by following this thread in [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46021), but no use it's not helping, signInwithphoneNumber only signs in user not verifies the user by sending SMS OTP code, how to solve this?

Github thread link:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46021

When I have implemented throwed the following error:

```
Error: UnimplementedError: verifyPhoneNumber() is not supported on the web. Please use 
`signInWithPhoneNumber` instead.
```

Can someone help me out please !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

// Wait for the user to complete the reCAPTCHA & for an SMS code to be sent.
ConfirmationResult confirmationResult = await auth.signInWithPhoneNumber('+44 7123 123 456');
```

then this to verify

```
UserCredential userCredential = await confirmationResult.confirm('123456');
```

You can also add **RecaptchaVerifier** as per your own use like

```
ConfirmationResult confirmationResult = await auth.signInWithPhoneNumber('+44 7123 123 456', RecaptchaVerifier(
  container: 'recaptcha',
  size: RecaptchaVerifierSize.compact,
  theme: RecaptchaVerifierTheme.dark,
));
```

and you can also edit reCaptcha

```
RecaptchaVerifier(
  onSuccess: () => print('reCAPTCHA Completed!'),
  onError: (FirebaseAuthException error) => print(error),
  onExpired: () => print('reCAPTCHA Expired!'),
);
```